# Configuring VMWare Server 2.0 with an HTTP proxy

Tags: vmware, vmware-server

I have configured a VMWare 2.0 server with a guest OS (Ubuntu Linux) and my host OS is Windows XP.

My XP machine connects to the Internet via an HTTP proxy. I wanted the guest OS in VMWare to have access to the Internet as well. The VM created has the network adapter set to NAT. I haven't really specified any other settings for the network for this VM (just followed the wizard).

When I try to open a website in the guest OS, it asks me for the HTTP authentication. I don't have to do this when using the host OS.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Comment: This is not programming related and belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Hi, ServerFault seems to be in private beta. Yeah, ok, I guess that this is not strictly a programming question but I figured quite a few people here would know the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an HTTP proxy on your network, your guest OS and apps in the guest will have to be setup to use it just like you did with host applications and the host OS.